# Esami doesn't generate string of correct answers

Tags: esami

Cannot get the string of correct answers from this

```
\documentclass[english]{article} %ESAMI FILE
    \usepackage[allowrandomize,shuffle,twocolumns]{esami} % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\r}{1\ }
\newcommand{\w}{0\ }
\newcommand{\two}[3]{\newproblem{
    \item
    \textbf{#1}
    \begin{answers}{2}
        \bChoices[random]
        \Ans#2 \eAns
        \Ans#3 \eAns
        \eChoices
    \end{answers}
}}
\def\numcompiti{2}
\date{2018/02/27}
\begin{document}
 \whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers%
    \FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
    \randomi=\seme

    \permuta

    \begin{test}
        \begin{questions}
            \selectallproblems[random]{cardio}
        \end{questions}
    \end{test}

    \closevers
 }
\end{document}
```

And now the cardio.tex

```
\two{Some random text}{\r Something right}{\w Something wrong}
```

It doesn't generate the string of correct answers (maybe this one is kinda easy to solve, but I couldn't find the solution). Please help.

Comment: I have compiled your code but I could not managed it to make it work properly. I have made some modifications and I was able to compile, but as I did not understand what you are trying to do with the new command `\two` that you have defined, I am not sure that what I get is what you want. Can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm working on two different projects (an esami file and a book} and both input the same tex file. I'm gathering a lot of MCQ in the book file along with their answers but I'll like to have a way to get some of these questions randomly scrambled so I can solve them later (obviously without the answers). Since I input the same file on both, I have to make it work for both. So I define the same command differently on each one. On the book I need a command to define a question but the number of choices varies. So I define \two for questions with two choices

Comment: Using 'shortcuts' such as `\w` and `\r`, the later even with a redefinition, you're asking for trouble...

Comment: On the book, it's \newtheorem{question}{Question}[section] \newcommand{\two}[3]{\begin{question} \textbf{#1} \begin{enumerate} \item #2 \item #3 \end{enumerate} \end{question}} \renewcommand{\r}{} \newcommand{\w}{}

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need to use them. As I explain, two files input the same cardio.tex and I can't manage to mark the correct answer on this file {for the esami} and not messing the other one {where I don't need to mark it}

Comment: @DanielChávez: Choose another names please. `\r` and `\w` is **bad**

Comment: @ChristianHupfer got it. Still isn't working though.

Answer (score 2):

@DanielChávez:

1. In the `esami` package, to generate correctly the answers string, you need to load a configuration file (i.e. the xyz.cfg which comes with the package and that you can name differently). The configuration file must be loaded inserting the option xyz (or any other name you chose) when you load the `esami` package.
2. You cannot use a parameter (\w or \r) to indicate the 0 or 1 of the correct or wrong answer. You must write

   ```
    \newcommand{\two}[3]{\newproblem{
    \item \PTs{number of points}
    \textbf{#1}
    \begin{answers}{2}
    \bChoices[random]
    \Ans1 #2 \eAns
    \Ans0 #3 \eAns
    \eChoices
    \end{answers}
    }}
   ```

   and in the cardio.tex file #2 and #3 must be written without \r or \w. Please note that you must indicate the number of points.
3. If you want the answers to be scrambled, you cannot use `\selectallproblems` but any other command for exercise choice (see the manual).

Comment: I've already done as you say, but still, everytime I load the xyz.cfg file, these happen:
Undefined control sequence. \ifluatex
Extra \else. \else
Undefined control sequence. \ifxetex
Extra \else. \else
Extra \fi. \ProcessOptions\relax
Extra \fi. \ProcessOptions\relax
Don't have a clue why and how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: You can avoid this error by commenting lines from 149 to 172 in the config file (from \ifluatex to \fi \fi).